# In Google App Engine custom run time, how can I cluster my TomEE instances?

Tags: google-app-engine, apache-tomee

I have a simple TomEE container with the Dockerfile

```
FROM tomee:8-jre-7.0.4-plus

WORKDIR /usr/local/tomee/webapps/

COPY server.xml /usr/local/tomee/conf/server.xml
COPY test-app.war /usr/local/tomee/webapps/ROOT.war

RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomee/webapps/ROOT

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 4000-4100
EXPOSE 45564
```

This is enough to run a cluster in my machine and get proper session replication, but when I deploy to Google App Engine, it's like the instances can't broadcast

This is my app.yaml

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 2
  max_num_instances: 2
network:
  forwarded_ports: 
    - 4000
    - 4001
    - 4002
    - 4003
    - 45564
```

I see a difference between my local logs and the logs in the Google App Engine

```
01-Mar-2018 17:19:45.607 SEVERE [main] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke FarmWarDeployer can only work as host cluster subelement!
```

Comment: As a workaround if you only want session replication for user authentication try JWT, it allows user authentication without need of server side sessions, https://jwt.io/

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I want to make the correction that the App Engine sits on top of Google Kubernetes Engine. The Google App Engine Flex(which is your case) is built on the Google Compute Engine instead (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/). And the network policies of Compute Engine apply to the Google App Engine Flexible.

Hence, the Configurable and flexible Virtual Private Cloud networking system that is offered by the Google Compute Engine also applies to the Google App Engine Flex. Every project is provided with a default VPC network with preset configurations and firewall rules, and all traffic from  outside world  to instances within your project, even from other instances, is blocked by the firewall unless firewall rules are created to explicitly allow the traffic (except the default VPC network that is created automatically with each project.) I think you should read the article in the link(https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networks-and-firewalls) for more details on the VPC Networking and Firewalls.

Comment: Yes, they can see each other, but they can't multicast to each other, multicast is forbidden it seams, if I enter the individual instances with SSH I can succesfuly ping each instance machine from each instance machine, but I cannot multicast

About the app engine being on top of kubernetes I think I misunderstood a presentation

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that at this time, the Google Compute Engine networking does not support both IPv4 broadcasts or multicasts. According to the last comment on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#specifications), VPC networks only support IPv4 unicast traffic. VPC network provides connectivity for Compute Engine virtual machine (VM) instances, App Engine Flex instances, and other resources in projects. Hence, Multicasts and Broadcasts are confirmed not supported in App Engine Flex